# Show that the Gamma Function can be expressed as $\Gamma(z) =\int_1^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(z+n)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

This question is from an assignment sheet which I am solving and I need help in solving following problem.

> Show that Gamma Function can be expressed
> $$\Gamma(z) =\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n } { n! (z+n)}$$

Using Definition of Gamma Function , $\Gamma(z) = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt + \int_{0}^{1} e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt $. but I am not able to co-orelate $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt $ with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n } { n! (z+n)}$ .

So, Can you please shed some light on this.

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: Hint: if $z$ has a positive real part, then $\frac{1}{z+n}=\int_0^1{t^nt^{z-1}\,dt}$ for every $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Another hint: expand $e^{-t}$ into its power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the integral definition of the gamma function we have
$$
\Gamma(z)
=\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1}\, \mathrm dt
=\int_1^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1}\, \mathrm dt+\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{z-1}\, \mathrm dt.
$$
All that is left is to find the series expansion for the second integral. Expanding the exponential term gives
$$
\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{z-1}\, \mathrm dt=\int_0^1 \lim_{N\to\infty}\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-t)^n}{n!} t^{z-1}}_{f_n(z)}\, \mathrm dt.
$$
Now note that on $t\in[0,1]$:
$$
|f_n(z)|<\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{t^n}{n!} |t^{z-1}|<e^t |t^{z-1}|\leq e t^{\Re z-1},
$$
which is integrable in $t\in[0,1]$ for all $\Re z>0$. Hence, by argument of dominated convergence
$$
\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{z-1}\, \mathrm dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1 t^{z+n-1}\, \mathrm dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n! (z+n)},
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: You probably need some absolute values in places because the inequalities contain complex numbers.